# How can I update and save one model from another in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my program, I have a model, Calorie, that takes what a person ate and gives them a point total. After that point value is calculated for each day's nutritional information, I want to update the 'points' variable in the User model.

The code I have in the Calorie model is

```
before_save :calculate_points

def calculate_points
    # snipped calculations
    User.where(user_id).first.point_calculation
end
```

In the User model, I have

```
def point_calculation
    self.points = Calorie.where(user_id: id).sum(:points)
end
```

I've tested the point_calculation model by creating a callback before_save, and it works fine there. But it makes a lot more sense to update after each new Calorie entry, instead of a user updating their settings. Any advice? What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your Calorie model has a has_one relationship with the User, and User has_many Calories.

In Calorie model:

```
after_save :update_user_points

def update_user_points
    self.user.update_calorie_points!
end
```

In User model:

```
def update_calorie_points!
    self.update_column(:points, self.calories.sum(:points))
end
```